# Adding ProcessBar to compress - SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, compression, progress-bar, sevenzipsharp

I want to add `process bar` when `SevenZipSharp` is compressing files/folders.

I wrote something like: (*check out comments*)

```
private void buttonCompress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"SevenZipSharp.dll"));
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8) //x64
            SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"7z64.dll"));
        else //x86
        SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"7z.dll"));


compressor.Compressing += new EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs>(compressor_Compressing); // <-- Handler for progressBar
...
...
...
```

and `Void` for `progressBar`:

```
void compressor_Compressing(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {   
      this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.Value = e.PercentDone;}));  
      //i tired this too: this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {compressor_Compressing(sender, e); }));
    }
```

But, as you probably guessed, doesn't work.

**Edit:**

ok so now i added:

```
void compressor_Compressing(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)   // <-- not necessary in this case
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);   //<-- this is the key to run progressBar
            this.Invoke((new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.Value = e.PercentDone; })));
     }
```

ProcessBar started **BUT** program frezzing about 97%-98% and nothing happens.
I think i must create new `Thread`. Can someone help me with it please?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does your program ever enter compressing event?

Comment: well i think it started but nothing else... only start without error but doesn't compress- freezed

Comment: i edited post. Can u check it pls?

Comment: You are fire-hosing the UI thread, invoking much more often than necessary.   The Sleep() call is a band-aid, slowing down the invoke rate.  And never use Invoke() if you can avoid it, very apt to cause deadlock.  Always use BeginInvoke() instead.

Comment: Well ok. I deleted all from compressor_Compressing and it's ok (of course except progressBar) but when ill add something to this void, application freeze. I changed invoke for BeginInvoke but nothing changed. I delete Sleep()- progressBar is running but again app freeze.

Comment: Anybody know, how can i repair this ?